# get specific value from array to return in NSIndexpath.row

Tags: arrays, swift, collectionview

i want my collection view to return only specific array. i want it to return only from "AUDI" to "Chevrolet" or [2...9]. the car make and new car make array, both have value of 8. they both should be the same but it give me error `fatal error: Index out of bounds`. what did i do wrong??

```
 var car make = ["Honda","Toyota","AUDI","Bentley","BMW","Mercedes","Buick","Cadillac","KIA","Chevrolet","Corvette","Dodge","FIAT","Ford","GMC","Hyundai","Infiniti","Jaguar","JEEP","LandRover","LEXUS","Mazda","Nissan","RAM","Porsche","Scion","Volkswagen"]

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return carmake[2...9].count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = viewcontrol.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! jobtypeCollectionViewCell

            let newcarmake = carmake[2...9]
            cell.title.text = newcarmake[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `2..8` vs `2..9`.

Comment: sorry that was typo. i change it to [2...9]. still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`carmake[2...9]` is not an array but an `ArraySlice`, and array slices
use the same indices as the array that they are created from.
So the valid indices for `carmake[2...9]` are `2...9`, and not `0...7`
as you probably expected.

One solution would be to create a real array instead:

```
let newcarmake = Array(carmake[2...9])
cell.title.text = newcarmake[indexPath.row]
```

Alternatively, reference the original array with a simple
offset calculation, for example

```
cell.title.text = carmake[indexPath.row + 2]
```

Comment: dude you are a lifesaver. i have been looking everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your `NSIndexPath`.
Your code is almost good. It needs a little change.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = viewcontrol.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! jobtypeCollectionViewCell

    cell.title.text = carmake[indexpath.row + 2]
    return cell
}
```

`newCarMake` is a text, not array. Try that code.